# Should I copy svn folders when working offsite?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

At my current location I can not access our SVN server. I copied my working folder (workplace location) on a DVD and have it on my notebook (home location ) right now.

How should I transfer the changed files to the server? I can't copy the complete project because the connection is too slow.

1. Copy only the changed files to the working folder on workplace location and commit the changes to the server
2. Copy changed files and svn folders of their parent directory to the wokplace location working folder and commit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just create a patch file of your changes.  As you seem to be using tortoise, here is info on [how to create and apply patches](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-patch.html) with tortoisesvn.  You can also do this [using the svn diff command](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/03/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-subversion/) and applying the patch file to another working copy using the patch command.

Comment: Any ideas on how this can work for binary files under SVN control?